# What is the consequence of modifying the server file during downloading on Nginx?

Tags: nginx

It seems that, on Nginx server, modifying the content of a file being downloaded could result in a broken and inconsistent file at the client end. Here's my experiment:

I built a Nginx server in a local network, and on that, there is a 1M file filling with 'a'. I download this file on my computer using curl (and the speed is limited slow enough). During the period of downloading, I overwrite this file on the server with another file with the same size but filled with 'b'. I did this step using Linux command 'cp' and no error occurs. Finally, when I check the downloaded result, it turns out to be a mixed file with 'a's at the first part and 'b's at the second part, like this way: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"

I'm wondering if it is the expected consequence. And if so, is there a way to tell the Nginx to reject any IO operations when there is still active connections, or simply return an error code and abort the connection after the file has changed? Since updating files may be a very common operation on the server, I imagine there should be some workarounds.

My testing environment:

```
Server OS: Linux 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 
2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Server file system: ext4

Nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Client OS: Windows 10

Client tool: curl 7.51.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.51.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2j 
zlib/1.2.8 libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.15.0 librtmp/2.3
```

Comment: What operating system are you using? What filesystem? What else about your environment might be relevant?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for your tips. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading a file that is being overwritten will have unpredictable results.

You will get much more predictable results by writing  your modifications to a temporary location (on the same file system) and rename (`mv`) the temporary file to replace the current version. Renaming files is atomic and instantaneous.

If your web server was (still) reading and transmitting the old version when you rename a file, it will continue to do so from that old version until that download is complete but any new requests for that file will get the new version.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41668/48232